# Mongoose is saying I have 46 records, mongoDB says I have zero?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

The following test script says I have 46 records:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DealSchema = new Schema({
  title : String,
});

var Deal = mongoose.model('Deal', DealSchema);  

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dealsite');
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(){
  console.log("Mongoose connected");
  Deal.count({}, function( err, count){
    console.log( "Records:", count );
  })
});
```

output:

```
$ node testmongo.js 
Mongoose connected
Records: 46
```

While if I try to read the cords using the mongo shell I get a different story:

```
$ mongo localhost/dealsite
MongoDB shell version: 1.4.4
url: localhost/dealsite
connecting to: localhost/dealsite
type "exit" to exit
type "help" for help
> db.dealsite.count()
0
> db.dealsite.Deal.count()
0
```

Where are my records hiding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MongoDB, try:

```
use dealsite
db.deals.count()
```

If you create a Mongoose model called "Deal", it will create and use a MongoDB collection called "deals".

Answer (score 2):

you missed the statement :

```
"use Deal"    [ use DATABASE_NAME ]
```

before doing

```
db.dealsite.count()
```

Comment: When I connect to the DB that way it's already using the `dealsite` database. I also tried just manually selecting the database, but it has no effect. There are examples of this way of connecting in the manual: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-Starting

Comment: yes , didn't see your connection string. sorry . what does a FIND or FINDONE on your collection return ?